# Does chicken manure keep cats away from garden areas?

Tags: zoology, ethology

[This article](http://www.cat-world.com.au/keeping-cats-out-of-gardens) mentions that chicken manure can keep cats away.

> Chicken manure around established plants can also deter cats as they don't like the smell.

Is it true?

Comment: I don't know if it will keep away cats but if it's fresh enough to smell then odds are it is going to "burn" and possibly kill the plant because of its high nitrogen content.
http://thecitychicken.com/chickenpooparticle.html

Comment: Given how many cats sneak around our backyard - we have three chicken - I'd guess it's a myth. But such first hand experience doesn't count much here, so I'll patiently wait for someone with a properly sourced answer. +1

Comment: I don't have any scientific backup, but I don't really need any. Around here, the cat's are fine walking through chicken manure, and I use it as a fertilizer on the soil, rather than a cat-deterrent. You could also ask this on GL, it would be on-topic there.